# Why I get this error message "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I've installed node.js on my computer and I've successfully tested this code on my computer with two opened web browsers.

The problem is, that the code is not working on the web server. I really don't why?

The codes are from this YouTube playlist:
[12: Web Sockets and p5.js Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6b36TzJidYfIYwTFEq3K5qH)

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Sockets Example 1</title> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="sketch.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**sketch.js**

```
var socket;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(200,200);
    background(51);

    //socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000'); ?
    socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');       

    socket.on('mouse', newDrawing);
}

function newDrawing(data) {
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 100);
    ellipse(data.x, data.y, 36, 36);            
}

function mouseDragged() {
    console.log('Sending: ' + mouseX + ',' + mouseY);       

    var data = {
        x: mouseX,
        y: mouseY
    }
    socket.emit('mouse', data);     

    noStroke();
    fill(255);
    ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 36, 36);
}
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000);

app.use(express.static('public'));

console.log("My socket server is running!");

var socket = require('socket.io');

var io = socket(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', newConnection);

function newConnection(socket) {
    console.log('new connection: ' + socket.id);

    socket.on('mouse', mouseMsg);   

    function mouseMsg(data) {
        socket.broadcast.emit('mouse', data);
    }   
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "sockets_example_1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "sockets example 1",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "sockets",
    "p5.js",
    "node"
  ],
  "author": "Noa",
  "license": "No license",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "socket.io": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

This is the folder structure:

```
├───node_modules
│   └───... (created files with node.js on my computer)
├───public
│   ├───index.html
│   └───sketch.js
├───package.json
├───package-lock.json
└───server.js
```

In chrome web browser I get this error message:

```
index.js:83 GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MqfwDDZ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

In firefox web browser I get this error message:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MqfvjtX. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

On my web server node.js is installed.

Comment: You need to connect with the IP of your webserver instead of localhost in `io.connect()`

Comment: There can be multiple reasons for connection refused error. Refer this link https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/hosting/technical-matters/err-connection-refused/

Comment: @DragonBorn: I used an online "Domain to IP converter". Changed localhost to the IP. Not working.

Comment: This is a security restriction on modern browsers these days, when you run JS code it is run locally on the users machine.  This presents a security risk as your website can be www.google.co.uk but you can effectively run JS code to make the user open up any other website like www.mybadwebsite.com - if the website you are sending the request to does not match the origin the user is on then it will be blocked unless the headers request and responses allow cross origins.